# Bind ng-options value and label to ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

I'm using `ng-options` to generate a select tag whose options are locations. The labels are the location names, and the values are the location ID (in database).

I've bound the value (location ID) to an `ng-model` attribute, but I'd also like to bind the label (location name) to a different `ng-model` attribute. (I need to separate the `id` field since this will be POSTed to a server that expects this particular attribute.) What's the best way to do this in Angular?

My code:

```
<div ng-app="app"><div ng-controller="edit">
  <select ng-model="purchase.pickUpLocationId" ng-options="loc.id as loc.name for loc in purchase.availableLocations"></select>

  <!-- This is the model not yet bound: -->
  <p>You have selected {{ purchase.pickUpLocationName }}</p>

</div></div>
```

---

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('edit', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.purchase = {
        pickUpLocationId: 30,
        availableLocations: [
            {id: 20, name: "Charleston, SC"},
            {id: 30, name: "Atlanta, GA"},
            {id: 40, name: "Richmond, VA"},
        ]
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change to the following and bind to the entire object. You'll still have access to `id` later on for whatever you wish to do with it

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="loc as loc.name for loc in purchase.availableLocations"></select>
```

---

```
<p>You have selected {{ selected.name }}</p>
<p>You havd id too! {{ selected.id }}</p>
```

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/e8mth5tb/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to use the default location set in the controller, even if I set `$scope.purchase.selected = {id: 30, name: "Atlanta, GA" };`. How should this be done?

Comment: @eirikir you can add something like `$scope.selected = $scope.purchase.availableLocations[1];`

Comment: Almost, but I actually need to GET and POST the `purchase` object to a backend server with a `pickUpLocationId` field. Would I need to loop through the `availableLocations` to find the matching object after GETing `purchase`? or can I somehow bind `pickUpLocationId` to `selected.id`? or does Angular convention dictate abstracting this problem to a separate module, e.g. for data serialization?

Comment: @eirikir this may be a good candidate for [`http` transformations](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). If you scroll down to per request transformations if you need to change your object property name

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to model as a hash first

```
{
   "20": "Charleston, SC",
   "30": "Atlanta, GA"
}
```

and then use `{{availableLocations[purchase.pickUpLocationId]}}`

and make ng-options as

```
<select ng-model="purchase.pickUpLocationId" ng-options="id as label for (id, label) in purchase.availableLocations"></select>
```

Comment: it should be `purchase.pickUpLocationId`

Comment: Are you saying I should store `availableLocations` as a hash? How would `ng-options` work in that case?

Comment: I have updated it. Thanks @jcubic for pointing out the typo, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Updated scniro answer

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
     <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="opt as opt.language for opt in tableResult.locales"></select>        
     <p>You have selected {{ selected.language }}</p>
     <p>You havd id too! {{ selected.localeId }}</p>
     <p>
     </p>
     <input type="text" value="{{selected.localeId}} : {{selected.language}}" style="width:50%;"/>

</div>
```

**[JSFIDDLE -Bind ng options value and label](http://jsfiddle.net/e8mth5tb/135/)**